# How to log/visualize data transfers on Azure / Windows Server?

Tags: .net, iis, azure, windows-server-2012

We have made a nice framework for hosting many websites, which are database driven.

The amount of sites is causing about 95,000 pageviews a month across several hundred sites and Azure is telling us that our data out is ~205gb of Data.

If we loosely calculate everything it seems to be about correct- if there was no caching. But we checked and we are definitely applying caching,bundling scripts and zipping data.

Is there any kind of tool or logger we can install on an Azure/ Or Windows server that can help us detect repeating queries that are chewing up bandwidth.

Its not so bad now, but we might grow another ten fold and we will be in deep trouble then.

Comment: Are all of your Azure services in the same data center? For example, queries from a cloud service in one data center to SQL Azure in another will cause data out charges.

Comment: Ahh. NO it is load balanced. we got 3 instances, 2 IIS and 1 SQL. You thinkg its all the SQL traffic?

Comment: I would look at that. It was one of the things we optimized in our azure deployments was reducing the number of times data moves between azure data centers.